# Run Python script when link on SVG is clicked

Tags: python-3.x, svg

I am generating a graph in SVG format using GraphViz. I can embed hyperlinks in the nodes.

I would like this SVG file to be served by a web server. When a user clicks one of the links, I want the server to run a Python script (with arguments dependent on the link) which generates a new SVG, and then display that SVG.

What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For something this small I would probably use Flask that would parse params:

```
from flask import request
from flask import Response

@app.route('/')
def generate_svg():
   params = request.args
   svg = SVGGenerate(**params)
   return Response(svg, mimetype='image/svg+xml')
```

Note that this is fairly insecure - you would have to clean the params to accept only allowed values.

You could use something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schema or https://cerberus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ to validate the data you are receiving from user.

Flask has a good docs explaining the rest of the stuff you need to know.

Comment: What is Flask? What is `@app.route('/')`? What do I do with the code that you posted?